# Recognise date format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I have working an iOS app in which I'm getting the date in the following format "+0800-20170424-1053100".

I need to display it in the following format "MMM dd,yyyy". Let me know how to do it?

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Comment: This format seems to work: `@"xxxx'-'yyyyMMdd'-'HHmmssS"`, but I don't know what's the use of the last zero, so I put `S`. Look at the doc to change it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

**Objective C**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"Z-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssS";// chang
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"+0800-20170424-1053100"];

dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MMM dd,yyyy";
NSString *pmamDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

**Swift 3**

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter.init()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Z-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssS"
let date : Date = dateFormatter.date(from: "+0800-20170424-1053100")!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
let finalString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(finalString)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Full Analytics of your date :**

**+0800    :** Which is indicate for TimeZone, Date formate use `Z` or `X`

**20170424 :** Which is year,month and date, Date formate user `yyyyMMdd`

**105310   :** Which is indicate time , Date formate `HHmmss`.

**0        :** Last one 0 is indicate : hours in days (pm/am). use `K` or `H`.

So according above analytics, Your date format is :

```
1. X-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssK
2. Z-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssK
3. Z-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssS
```

So, you are put this formate as [@KKRocks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3901620/kkrocks) answer:

```
let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter.init()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "X-yyyyMMdd-HHmmssK"
let date : Date = dateFormatter.date(from: "+0800-20170424-1053100")!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"
let finalString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(finalString)
```